# OIDC .Net Desktop based application - Get access token without using Browser control (WebBrowser / WebView2)

Tags: c#, winforms, oauth-2.0, oidc-client

I am having a .Net Desktop based application (WinForm - .Net framework 4.8). As the backend services are using OAuth2.0, I required to generate accessToken and pass it as header.

Since it's desktop app I am using Authorization Code Grant type which requires redirect URL. My implementation is using library "IdentityModel.OidcClient" which requires "Browser" parameter to redirect.
Here is the sample.
https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/main/WinFormsWebView2

**I have exact same implementation as per the above sample which works overall however, it takes around 8 secs to get AccessToken which is too much.**

**Around 60% of time is going in my navigation code** (callback happens from OIDCClient lib) where it redirects to my redirect URl and returns "authorization code" to library.
I am suspecting use of full web browser / webview2 control to get access token is overhead here.

**Is there any other option where without WebBrowser control I can get access token with Authorization Code as a grant type ?**

If not how to improve performance as this much time is nearly not acceptable while opening of application as well as at every one hour when token gets expired.

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: Just to add, I am know about Refresh Token so that I won't require to Login again and again as it will have longer duration validity however, still opening of application is a major concern and taking 8 seconds is too much anyway.